# Hacer un inicio de sesión contra bases de datos con session_start - PHP

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin, login, sesiones

Mi problema es que solo me retorna el mensaje **adiós**, es decir, que el usuario no llega a iniciar sesión, ni a crear las variables de sesión.

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
    <body>
        <form METHOD="POST" ACTION="control.php">
            <br>Nom<br>
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="nombre">
            <br><br>Contrasenya<br>
            <INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="contrasena"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*PHP*

```
<?php
$usuario = $_POST['nombre'];
$pass = $_POST['contrasena'];
mysqli_connect('localhost','root','alumne');
mysqli_select_db('examen');
$result =mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuaris WHERE nom='".$usuario ."' AND passwd='".$pass ."'");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    if($row['contrasena'] === $pass){

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['nom'];
        echo hola;
    }
}
else{
    echo adios;
}
?>
```

Comment: Pon el codigo php antes de cargar el html y usa `session_start()` antes de hacer cualquier de las funcionas, además, lo que muestres con `echo` debe de ir entrecomillado: `echo "hola"`

Comment: Gracias. Pero el código html y php están en diferentes ficheros uno seria el formulario html y el otro el archivo de control php

Comment: Aún asi, `session_start()` va lo primero de todo

Comment: Okey. Gracias he hecho todo pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Has comprobado que la query esté bien? La tabla se llama `usuaris`?

Comment: me parece que el problema lo tienes en la consulta mysql, ademas confirma si el nombre de la base de datos es el correcto, dentro de la consulta mysql (Query)

Comment: Hola joan saez, si se me permite una recomendación: no desarrolles tu propio login hasta que no tengas algunos conceptos de seguridad claros. El código compartido presenta vulnerabilidades y problemas muy graves de seguridad: inyección SQL, contraseñas sin encriptar/hashear, contraseñas en el propio código, no expiración de sesiones, id se sesión permanente... y no debería ser utilizado en entornos de cara al público. Si lo estás desarrollando para hacer pruebas y aprender, deberías mirar al menos los problemas que te comento.

Comment: Okey. Gracias a todos el problema estaba en la consulta.